# java package showing error

Tags: java, package

I made a java package in my d drive(os is windows). The name of the package is animals. in one java file named Animal.java I wrote:

```
package animals;
   interface Animal   
   {
    public void eat();   
    public void travel();
   }
```

in another java file named MammalInt.java i wrote:

```
package animals;

public class MammalInt implements Animal {

public MammalInt() {
    System.out.println(this.getClass().getCanonicalName());
}

public void eat() {
    System.out.println("Mammal eats");
}

public void travel() {
    System.out.println("Mammal travels");
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    MammalInt m = new MammalInt();
    m.eat();
    m.travel();
}
}
```

When i compile MammalInt.java the error comes:`MammalInt.java:5: error: cannot find symbol public class MammalInt implements Animal`...can any one please solve it??

Comment: sorry... as my reputation is less the three so i could post images...sorry for that in convenience ....

Answer (score 0):

In Java the package structure must 
reflect the directory structure.

So create a sub-folder called animals.
In my example I am in C:\Various\code\ and 
the sub-folder is C:\Various\code\animals.

So put your two java files there (in the animals sub-folder).

Then go to the parent folder and compile like this.

```
    C:\Various\code>dir

     Directory of C:\Various\code

    12/24/2013  05:33 AM    <DIR>          .
    12/24/2013  05:33 AM    <DIR>          ..
    12/24/2013  05:34 AM    <DIR>          animals
                   0 File(s)              0 bytes
                   3 Dir(s)  49,286,955,008 bytes free

    C:\Various\code>javac -cp . ./animals/*.java

    C:\Various\code>
```

Here -cp specifies the classpath to use. The . tells the compiler 
to include the current folder in the classpath while compiling.

Answer (score 0):

In java you are expected to store your classes in a directory path equal to the package.  For example, assuming you have your project in d:\users\fitrat\project:

```
d:\users\fitrat\project
d:\users\fitrat\project\animals\Animal.java
d:\users\fitrat\project\animals\MammalInt.java
```

Did you remember to do so?

Comment: thx Jorge_B for your reply...May directory structure is
D:\animals
D:\animals\animal.java
D:\animals\MammalInt.java

Comment: I would not advice working in D:\, but if you are doing so, then try compiling it from D:\ (which is actually your project root) and not from d:\animals

Comment: i copied the two files into D: and compiled. There is no error. But when i run the MammalInt.java then it shows java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: MammalInt (wrong name: animals/MammalInt)......for your information i am using SciTe text editor and compiling ang run from there.....

Comment: I am sorry, that is not what I meant.  My idea was: keep your original structure, but compile from D:\ and see if you get the same error